# Portfolio Optimize in R with ONLY a vector of mean returns and covariance matrix

Tags: r, optimization, r-portfolioanalytics

Every package that I look at seems to require time series returns for my assets.

For example I like the PortfolioAnalytics package, and I require many of the constraints offered (box constraints, group constraints, etc.). However, as far as I can tell it requires some sort of time series of returns, even if I specify my own moments (I could be wrong).

**All I have are the expected returns of each of my 14 assets and the covariance matrix.**

How can I do various forms of optimizations with that as my starting point? Ultimately I'd like to build a full efficient frontier as well as be able to maximize return at a given level of risk (standard deviation) given my constraints. If I had a time series this wouldn't be a problem...but alas I do not.

Thanks. I feel like this should be quite easy but I've been running in circles.

Worst case scenario is I could build a fake time series that fits the parameters of the E(R) and covariance matrix..if you think this is my solution can you offer me an easy way to do that...but that is why I am here :)

Comment: might be relevant: https://cvxr.rbind.io/cvxr_examples/cvxr_portfolio-optimization/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a particular package, and that
particular package allows only time-series, then yes,
the only way for you to use that particular package is
to create time-series that match your means and
variance-covariance-matrix. (But you might want to
check the way the package computes the
means/variance-covariance-matrix from these
time-series.)  See
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58293991](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58293991/how-to-use-fportfolio-package-in-r-for-non-time-series-input/58302451#58302451) for how to create such series.

For mean-variance optimisation, requiring time-series
(and not providing an alternative, overriding method) would be a
bad design choice on part of a package. (And I find it hard to believe that `PortfolioAnalytics` should not offer such a mechanism.) The input for
mean-variance optimisation is a forecast of the means
and a forecast of the variance-covariance matrix. Such
forecasts may be informed by, or based on, historical
data.  But even then there are many different
possibilities to compute such quantities,
e.g. shrinkage.

In any case, the [`NMOF` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=NMOF), which I maintain, has functions `minvar` and `mvPortfolio`
for computing minimum-variance and mean-variance-efficient portfolios based on mean vectors and variance-covariance matrices. In the [development of version of `NMOF`](https://github.com/enricoschumann/NMOF), those function also allow the specification of group constraints.

Comment: Awesome! Fantastic package. I’m not married to any particular package so I’ll definitely take yours for a test drive. From what I can tell you aren’t offering group constraints, just min/max on assets. Any plans for that? Also are your forcing it to be fully invested (add up to 1), I didn’t see anything on that either. Thanks again!

Comment: The group constraint is a potential deal killer. For example about half my assets are equities and the other half are fixed income. Total equities is constrained around 60-80% and fixed 20%-40%. The individual constraints aren’t sufficient to achieve that constraint. Any way I can do that in your package? If not, any plans to add?

Comment: Thank you. The portfolios are always fully invested. Group constraints are not implemented. But I just looked at the functions, and it should not be too difficult to add them. If you were willing to test them, I might implement such constraints. (The latest version of `NMOF` is at https://github.com/enricoschumann/NMOF .)

Comment: For the record, group constraints are now available in the development version of `NMOF`. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
library(stockPortfolio)
library(quadprog)
library(ggplot2)
stocks <- c("SPY",  "EFA",  "IWM",  "VWO",  "LQD",  "HYG")

returns <- getReturns(stocks, freq = "week")

eff.frontier <-  function (returns,
                           short = "no",
                           max.allocation = NULL,
                           risk.premium.up = .5,
                           risk.increment = .005) {
  covariance <- cov(returns)
  print(covariance)
  n <- ncol(covariance)

  # Create initial Amat and bvec assuming only equality constraint (short-selling is allowed, no allocation constraints)
  Amat <- matrix (1, nrow = n)
  bvec <- 1
  meq <- 1

  # Then modify the Amat and bvec if short-selling is prohibited
  if (short == "no") {
    Amat <- cbind(1, diag(n))
    bvec <- c(bvec, rep(0, n))
  }

  # And modify Amat and bvec if a max allocation (concentration) is specified
  if (!is.null(max.allocation)) {
    if (max.allocation > 1 | max.allocation < 0) {
      stop("max.allocation must be greater than 0 and less than 1")
    }
    if (max.allocation * n < 1) {
      stop("Need to set max.allocation higher; not enough assets to add to 1")
    }
    Amat <- cbind(Amat, -diag(n))
    bvec <- c(bvec, rep(-max.allocation, n))
  }

  # Calculate the number of loops based on how high to vary the risk premium and by what increment
  loops <- risk.premium.up / risk.increment + 1
  loop <- 1

  # Initialize a matrix to contain allocation and statistics
  # This is not necessary, but speeds up processing and uses less memory
  eff <- matrix(nrow = loops, ncol = n + 3)
  # Now I need to give the matrix column names
  colnames(eff) <-
    c(colnames(returns), "Std.Dev", "Exp.Return", "sharpe")

  # Loop through the quadratic program solver
  for (i in seq(from = 0, to = risk.premium.up, by = risk.increment)) {
    dvec <-
      colMeans(returns) * i # This moves the solution up along the efficient frontier
    sol <-
      solve.QP(
        covariance,
        dvec = dvec,
        Amat = Amat,
        bvec = bvec,
        meq = meq
      )
    eff[loop, "Std.Dev"] <-
      sqrt(sum(sol$solution * colSums((
        covariance * sol$solution
      ))))
    eff[loop, "Exp.Return"] <-
      as.numeric(sol$solution %*% colMeans(returns))
    eff[loop, "sharpe"] <-
      eff[loop, "Exp.Return"] / eff[loop, "Std.Dev"]
    eff[loop, 1:n] <- sol$solution
    loop <- loop + 1
  }

  return(as.data.frame(eff))
}

eff <-
  eff.frontier(
    returns = returns$R,
    short = "yes",
    max.allocation = .45,
    risk.premium.up = .5,
    risk.increment = .001
  )


eff.optimal.point <- eff[eff$sharpe == max(eff$sharpe),]

ealred  <- "#7D110C"
ealtan  <- "#CDC4B6"
eallighttan <- "#F7F6F0"
ealdark  <- "#423C30"
ggplot(eff, aes(x = Std.Dev, y = Exp.Return)) + geom_point(alpha = .1, color =
                                                             ealdark) +
  geom_point(
    data = eff.optimal.point,
    aes(x = Std.Dev, y = Exp.Return, label = sharpe),
    color = ealred,
    size = 5
  ) +
  annotate(
    geom = "text",
    x = eff.optimal.point$Std.Dev,
    y = eff.optimal.point$Exp.Return,
    label = paste(
      "Risk: ",
      round(eff.optimal.point$Std.Dev * 100, digits = 3),
      "\nReturn: ",
      round(eff.optimal.point$Exp.Return * 100, digits =
              4),
      "%\nSharpe: ",
      round(eff.optimal.point$sharpe * 100, digits = 2),
      "%",
      sep = ""
    ),
    hjust = 0,
    vjust = 1.2
  ) +
  ggtitle("Efficient Frontier\nand Optimal Portfolio") + labs(x = "Risk (standard deviation of portfolio variance)", y =
                                                                "Return") +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = eallighttan),
    text = element_text(color = ealdark),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 24, color = ealred)
  )
```

This should help as well.

https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-finance-using-r-efficient-frontier-and-capm-part-1/