Solving in optimize.portfolio with just a vector of expected returns
#cov matrix
cov_matrix_d <- as.matrix(data[10:15, 2:7])
cov_matrix_d <- apply(cov_matrix_d, 2, as.numeric)
R <- as.numeric(data[6, 2:7])
port <- portfolio.spec(assets = colnames(cov_matrix_d))
#constraints
port <- add.constraint(port, type = "full_investment")
port <- add.constraint(port, type = "long_only")
port <- add.constraint(port, type = "turnover", turnover = 0.7)
#obj
port <- add.objective(port, type = "return", name = "mean", target = target_return)
port <- add.objective(port, type = "risk", name = "StdDev")

opt <- optimize.portfolio(R = R, covmat = cov_matrix_d, portfolio = port,     optimize_method = "ROI")


> opt <- optimize.portfolio(R = R, covmat = cov_matrix_d, portfolio = port,  optimize_method = "ROI")
Error in ROI::V_bound(li = seq.int(1L, N), lb = as.numeric(lb), ui = seq.int(1L,  : 
duplicated entries in indices.

I keep getting an error which I suspect is due to the fact I am not using a time series of returns, and just use a vector with a single expected return for each stock. I also add the error I get. Could someone maybe help?
I don't have the raw data for this problem as my professor only gave an excel file with expected return and cov_matrix. Normally I just use the quadprog library, but adding a turnover constraint proved difficult so I decided to give the PortfolioAnalytics library a chance.

If all else fails, you could generate time-series data that exactly give the specified mean return and specified covariance matrix. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58293991/how-to-use-fportfolio-package-in-r-for-non-time-series-input/58302451#58302451
